# Creating Batch file to Run a Blue Prism Process

Tags: batch-file, cmd, blueprism, rpa

I need to create a .bat file in order to run my Blue Prism process via CMD.

The commands are as follows (in order):

```
cd C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate
AutomateC.exe /user umang abcd1234 /run MyDemoProcess
```

Pardon if my question looks too basic as I am new to this stuff.

Comment: just put those lines into a file, save it with extension `.bat` or `.cmd`. Be sure to save it with encoding "ANSI". Although your commands work, make the first one syntactically correct (and more secure) with `cd /d "C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate"

Comment: Just take account that you don't generally need to change your working directory in order to run an exectuable file. I would assume that your command is expecting `MyDemoProcess` to be located in the current directory, as you have not provided its path. My general advice would therefore be to use, `"F:\ull Path\To\AutomateC.exe" … /run "L:\ocation of\MyDemoProcess"`, or `CD /D "L:\ocation of"` followed by `"F:\ull Path\To\AutomateC.exe" … /run MyDemoProcess`, or `Start /D "L:\ocation of" "F:\ull Path\To\AutomateC.exe" … /run MyDemoProcess`.

Comment: It is also possible that your exectuable already looks for MyDemoProcess in a known or relative place. For that reason I would try first by simply removing the `CD` command, e.g. `"F:\ull Path\To\AutomateC.exe" … /run MyDemoProcess`

Answer (score 0):

In order to run any process from a batch file, please follow the below steps:

1) Open a notepad and type the below command :

"C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate\AutomateC.exe" /user umang abcd1234 /run "MyDemoProcess"

2) Save the file with .bat extension e.g. Test.bat. Once the saveAs window appears, please enter Test.bat in the FileName textbox and in SaveAs Type dropdown, please select All Files so that it takes the .bat extension.

3) Now whenever you will open the batch file it will trigger your process.

**Note** Please make sure your runtime resource is connected to the app server and you are able to see your runtime resource running otherwise the above batch file won't work